# Duplicate file error: android using javaCV

Tags: java, android

I have gone thorough many forums and I was unable to solve this,may be I missed something or I was unable to implement the solution in proper way.

I'm making face recognition app using javacv and while deploying on machine I got following error

> Error:Execution failed for task
>
> :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'. com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK org/bytedeco/javacpp/macosx-x86_64/libusb-1.0.dylib
>      File1: C:\Users.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets\libdc1394\2.2.4-1.3\f1498dacc46162ab68faeb8d66cf02b96fe41c61\libdc1394-2.2.4-1.3-macosx-x86_64.jar
>   File2: C:\Users.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets\libfreenect\0.5.3-1.3\736d65a3ef042258429d8e7742128c411806b432\libfreenect-0.5.3-1.3-macosx-x86_64.jar

for finding where is the duplicate file I ran

```
 gradlew app:dependencies
```

and found this output (unable to find file i.e libusb-1.0.dylib (may be I'm looking for wrong file)).

```
C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\faceDetectCV>gradlew app:dependencies
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.                           
:app:dependencies                                                                 
------------------------------------------------------------
Project :app
------------------------------------------------------------
_debugAndroidTestAnnotationProcessor - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies
_debugAndroidTestApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
     +--- com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
     +--- com.android.support.test:rules:0.5
     |    \--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.5
     |         +--- junit:junit:4.12
     |         |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
     |         \--- com.android.support.test:exposed-instrumentation-api-publish:0.5
     +--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.5 (*)
     +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
     +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
     |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
     +--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.2
     +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
     |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3 (*)
     +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
     \--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2

_debugAndroidTestCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
     +--- com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
     +--- com.android.support.test:rules:0.5
     |    \--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.5
     |         +--- junit:junit:4.12
     |         |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
     |         \--- com.android.support.test:exposed-instrumentation-api-publish:0.5
     +--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.5 (*)
     +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
     +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
     |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
     +--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.2
     +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
     |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3 (*)
     +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
     \--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
_debugAnnotationProcessor - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_debugApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0 (*)
\--- org.bytedeco:javacv-platform:1.3
     +--- org.bytedeco:javacv:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.1.0-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:3.2.1-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture:2.9.3.43-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:2.2.4-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:0.5.3-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:librealsense:1.9.6-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput:0.200-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:2.3.1-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:1.07-1.3
     |         +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.1.0-1.3 (*)
     |         \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv-platform:3.1.0-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.1.0-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg-platform:3.2.1-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:3.2.1-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture-platform:2.9.3.43-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture:2.9.3.43-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394-platform:2.2.4-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:2.2.4-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect-platform:0.5.3-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:0.5.3-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:librealsense-platform:1.9.6-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:librealsense:1.9.6-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput-platform:0.200-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput:0.200-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus-platform:2.3.1-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:2.3.1-1.3 (*)
     \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark-platform:1.07-1.3
          +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv-platform:3.1.0-1.3 (*)
          \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:1.07-1.3 (*)

_debugCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0 (*)
\--- org.bytedeco:javacv-platform:1.3
     +--- org.bytedeco:javacv:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.1.0-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:3.2.1-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture:2.9.3.43-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:2.2.4-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:0.5.3-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:librealsense:1.9.6-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput:0.200-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:2.3.1-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:1.07-1.3
     |         +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.1.0-1.3 (*)
     |         \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv-platform:3.1.0-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.1.0-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg-platform:3.2.1-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:3.2.1-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture-platform:2.9.3.43-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture:2.9.3.43-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394-platform:2.2.4-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:2.2.4-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect-platform:0.5.3-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:0.5.3-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:librealsense-platform:1.9.6-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:librealsense:1.9.6-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput-platform:0.200-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput:0.200-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus-platform:2.3.1-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:2.3.1-1.3 (*)
     \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark-platform:1.07-1.3
          +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv-platform:3.1.0-1.3 (*)
          \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:1.07-1.3 (*)

_debugUnitTestAnnotationProcessor - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_debugUnitTestApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- junit:junit:4.12
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

_debugUnitTestCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- junit:junit:4.12
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

_releaseAnnotationProcessor - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_releaseApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0 (*)
\--- org.bytedeco:javacv-platform:1.3
     +--- org.bytedeco:javacv:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.1.0-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:3.2.1-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture:2.9.3.43-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:2.2.4-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:0.5.3-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:librealsense:1.9.6-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput:0.200-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:2.3.1-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:1.07-1.3
     |         +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.1.0-1.3 (*)
     |         \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv-platform:3.1.0-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.1.0-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg-platform:3.2.1-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:3.2.1-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture-platform:2.9.3.43-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture:2.9.3.43-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394-platform:2.2.4-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:2.2.4-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect-platform:0.5.3-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:0.5.3-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:librealsense-platform:1.9.6-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:librealsense:1.9.6-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput-platform:0.200-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput:0.200-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus-platform:2.3.1-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:2.3.1-1.3 (*)
     \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark-platform:1.07-1.3
          +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv-platform:3.1.0-1.3 (*)
          \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:1.07-1.3 (*)

_releaseCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0 (*)
\--- org.bytedeco:javacv-platform:1.3
     +--- org.bytedeco:javacv:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.1.0-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:3.2.1-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture:2.9.3.43-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:2.2.4-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:0.5.3-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:librealsense:1.9.6-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput:0.200-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:2.3.1-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:1.07-1.3
     |         +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.1.0-1.3 (*)
     |         \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv-platform:3.1.0-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.1.0-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg-platform:3.2.1-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:3.2.1-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture-platform:2.9.3.43-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture:2.9.3.43-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394-platform:2.2.4-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:2.2.4-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect-platform:0.5.3-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:0.5.3-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:librealsense-platform:1.9.6-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:librealsense:1.9.6-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput-platform:0.200-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput:0.200-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus-platform:2.3.1-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:2.3.1-1.3 (*)
     \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark-platform:1.07-1.3
          +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv-platform:3.1.0-1.3 (*)
          \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:1.07-1.3 (*)

_releaseUnitTestAnnotationProcessor - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_releaseUnitTestApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- junit:junit:4.12
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

_releaseUnitTestCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- junit:junit:4.12
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

androidJacocoAgent - The Jacoco agent to use to get coverage data.
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.5.201505241946

androidJacocoAnt - The Jacoco ant tasks to use to get execute Gradle tasks.
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant:0.7.5.201505241946
     +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.5.201505241946
     |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.1
     +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:0.7.5.201505241946
     |    +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.5.201505241946 (*)
     |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.1
     \--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.5.201505241946

androidTestAnnotationProcessor - Classpath for the annotation processor for 'androidTest'.
No dependencies

androidTestApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'androidTest' classes.
No dependencies

androidTestCompile - Classpath for compiling the androidTest sources.
\--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
     +--- com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
     +--- com.android.support.test:rules:0.5
     |    \--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.5
     |         +--- junit:junit:4.12
     |         |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
     |         \--- com.android.support.test:exposed-instrumentation-api-publish:0.5
     +--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.5 (*)
     +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
     +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
     |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
     +--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.2
     +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
     |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3 (*)
     +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
     \--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2

androidTestProvided - Classpath for only compiling the androidTest sources.
No dependencies

androidTestWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'androidTest'.
No dependencies

annotationProcessor - Classpath for the annotation processor for 'main'.
No dependencies

apk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'main' classes.
No dependencies

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0 (*)
\--- org.bytedeco:javacv-platform:1.3
     +--- org.bytedeco:javacv:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.1.0-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:3.2.1-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture:2.9.3.43-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:2.2.4-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:0.5.3-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:librealsense:1.9.6-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput:0.200-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:2.3.1-1.3
     |    |    \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:1.07-1.3
     |         +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.1.0-1.3 (*)
     |         \--- org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv-platform:3.1.0-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.1.0-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg-platform:3.2.1-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:3.2.1-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture-platform:2.9.3.43-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture:2.9.3.43-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394-platform:2.2.4-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:2.2.4-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect-platform:0.5.3-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:0.5.3-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:librealsense-platform:1.9.6-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:librealsense:1.9.6-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput-platform:0.200-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput:0.200-1.3 (*)
     +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus-platform:2.3.1-1.3
     |    \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:2.3.1-1.3 (*)
     \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark-platform:1.07-1.3
          +--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv-platform:3.1.0-1.3 (*)
          \--- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:1.07-1.3 (*)

debugAnnotationProcessor - Classpath for the annotation processor for 'debug'.
No dependencies

debugApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'debug' classes.
No dependencies

debugCompile - Classpath for compiling the debug sources.
No dependencies

debugProvided - Classpath for only compiling the debug sources.
No dependencies

debugWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'debug'.
No dependencies

default - Configuration for default artifacts.
No dependencies

default-mapping - Configuration for default mapping artifacts.
No dependencies

default-metadata - Metadata for the produced APKs.
No dependencies

provided - Classpath for only compiling the main sources.
No dependencies

releaseAnnotationProcessor - Classpath for the annotation processor for 'release'.
No dependencies

releaseApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'release' classes.
No dependencies

releaseCompile - Classpath for compiling the release sources.
No dependencies

releaseProvided - Classpath for only compiling the release sources.
No dependencies

releaseWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'release'.
No dependencies

testAnnotationProcessor - Classpath for the annotation processor for 'test'.
No dependencies

testApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'test' classes.
No dependencies

testCompile - Classpath for compiling the test sources.
\--- junit:junit:4.12
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

testDebugAnnotationProcessor - Classpath for the annotation processor for 'testDebug'.
No dependencies

testDebugApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'testDebug' classes.
No dependencies

testDebugCompile - Classpath for compiling the testDebug sources.
No dependencies

testDebugProvided - Classpath for only compiling the testDebug sources.
No dependencies

testDebugWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'testDebug'.
No dependencies

testProvided - Classpath for only compiling the test sources.
No dependencies

testReleaseAnnotationProcessor - Classpath for the annotation processor for 'testRelease'.
No dependencies

testReleaseApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'testRelease' classes.
No dependencies

testReleaseCompile - Classpath for compiling the testRelease sources.
No dependencies

testReleaseProvided - Classpath for only compiling the testRelease sources.
No dependencies

testReleaseWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'testRelease'.
No dependencies

testWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'test'.
No dependencies

wearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'main'.
No dependencies

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 32.713 secs
```

here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ali.facedetectcv"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv-platform', version: '1.3'
}
```

and i have tried [this](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/591) and [this](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/586),with no result

Answer (score 1):

I've met the same problem and just excluded the file:

```java
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'org/bytedeco/javacpp/macosx-x86_64/libusb-1.0.dylib'
}
```